# Rank DataFrame based on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ranking

How can I rank a DataFrame based on 2 columns?

On below example, `col_b` would the tie breaker for `col_a`.

**DataFrame:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'col_b':[5,2,8,3,7,4]})

df
   col_a  col_b
0      0      5
1      0      2
2      0      8
3      1      3
4      1      7
5      1      4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   col_a  col_b  Rank
0      0      5   2
1      0      2   1
2      0      8   3
3      1      3   4
4      1      7   6
5      1      4   5
```

Comment: You could do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604665/python-pandas-rank-by-column with an intermediate grouping. i.e. `col_a_Rank` and group on that and rank `col_b` to get final `Rank` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one-line approach using `sort_values`:

```
In [135]: df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['col_a', 'col_b'])['col_b'].index + 1

In [136]: df
Out[136]: 
   col_a  col_b  rank
0      0      5     2
1      0      2     1
2      0      8     3
3      1      3     4
4      1      7     6
5      1      4     5
```

The logic behind this snippet: Basically, the `DataFrame.sort_values` function accepts multiple column names and returns a sorted copy of the dataframe based on the order of passed column names. The default sorting order is `ascending` which is what we want. If you wanted another order you could pass the order as an iterable of booleans to the `ascending` keyword argument. At the end the new indices of the `column_b` is what we want (plus one).

Comment: I was trying to avoid sorting. Not sure how it affects performance on a big DataFrame. But the solution works great. I will test it against the solution I gave to check which one is faster.

Comment: Depending on your dataframe, you might need to reset the index first. Similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279404/how-do-i-create-a-rank-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. Create a temp DataFrame by sorting the columns and re-indexing. Then use the new index as the rank and join back to the original df.

```
temp_df = df.sort_values(['col_a', 'col_b']).reset_index()
temp_df['rank'] = temp_df.index + 1
print(temp_df)
#   index  col_a  col_b  rank
#0      1      0      2     1
#1      0      0      5     2
#2      2      0      8     3
#3      3      1      3     4
#4      5      1      4     5
#5      4      1      7     6
```

The column `'index'` corresponds to the index in the original DataFrame. Use this to join `temp_df` back to `df` and select the columns you want:

```
df = df.join(temp_df.set_index('index'), rsuffix="_r")[['col_a', 'col_b', 'rank']]
print(df)
#   col_a  col_b  rank
#0      0      5     2
#1      0      2     1
#2      0      8     3
#3      1      3     4
#4      1      7     6
#5      1      4     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Found my own solution: Create a tuple with the columns and rank it. 
Won't handle different ascending/descending order, but it is good for my problem.

```
df['rank'] = df[['col_a','col_b']].apply(tuple, 1).rank()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`'s [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'col_b':[5,2,8,3,7,4]})
df["rank"] = np.argsort(
              df.values.copy().view(dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int)]).flatten(),  
              order=("x","y")
             ) + 1


    col_a   col_b   rank
0   0        5       2
1   0        2       1
2   0        8       3
3   1        3       4
4   1        7       6
5   1        4       5
```